# What's the difference between "./" and "/" when using Apache related programs?

Tags: symbols, bin, operation

I don't know if it's actually Unix operation, but there are often times when the instruction says we should use "./bin/WHATEVER" while other times says "/bin/WHATEVER"

What's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A period means the current directory and a path that starts with a `/` is the very root of the partition. So this:

```
./bin/whatever
```

Means a folder called `bin` inside the current directory. Whereas this:

```
/bin/whatever
```

Means the `bin` folder is in the root of the partition.

Comment: so if I'm currently in `<my_dir>`, `./bin` gives me `<my_dir>/bin` while `/bin` gives me, well, `/bin` where the `bin` directory is under `/`, is that correct?